# sublime text 3 se congela cada ves que trato de ejecutar algo en "run current file"

Tags: sublimetext3

Estoy tomando un curso por internet de phyton y el profesor esta impartiendo el curso con sublime text 3, llevo alrededor de dos semanas tomando el curso, pero hace 2 dias, sublime text 3 me va super mal, cada vez que quiero ejecutar algo en consola "run current file" para ser especifico, se me congela y tengo que cerrar y habrir el programa de nuevo. Conforme seguia programando, comenzo a ser mas frecuente, ya no se que hacer eh hecho de todo, ya lo desinstale y todo eso, aun tengo ese problema..

Todos los programas de mi laptop ma van super bien, salvo este.

Por favor necesito ayuda, no se casi nada acerca de esto porque es el primer curso de programacion que tomo :((

Answer (score 0):

print("Coffe 0k")

print("los cafes que estan disponibles al publico son: "
""" 
    tibetano
    salpete
    capuchino """)

eleccionCafe=input("selecciona el cafe de tu agrado: ")

contador_no_introducirNada=0

while eleccionCafe=="nada":
    print("no puedes dejar en nada")

esto es lo el ultimo codigo que escribi (se que es basico y erroneo) pero ala mejor eh escrito algo que me aya generado este problema